# How to render Primeng Components dynamically in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, primeng, software-design

My requirement is to render Primeng components along with normal html elements dynamically, The template to render is in a string form like below

```
   const dynamicTemplate =
      `<div class="card flex flex-row gap-3 justify-content-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Normal Button</button>
  <p-button label="Primary"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Secondary" styleClass="p-button-secondary"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Success" styleClass="p-button-success"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Info" styleClass="p-button-info"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Warning" styleClass="p-button-warning"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Help" styleClass="p-button-help"></p-button>
  <p-button label="Danger" styleClass="p-button-danger"></p-button>
</div>`
```

Now I want to render this template dynamically when some condition is satisfied.

The problem with this is very clear, primeng components need to be registered with the application in order for Angular to recognize them.

I have used `ComponentFactoryResolver` in order to create component dynamically and inject template into it, but it only renders normal html but not primeng components. Also I have used `[innerHtml]` as well but it also did not work.

Is there anyway primeng components can be rendered dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly render this template from string, you need to parse it first and then render each component separately. I recommend using other format of storing this information than simple string (for example JSON describing each component, but it heavily depends on your use case), because it might be easier to work with.

As of Angualar v13 you can use [ViewContainerRef.createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) and pass PrimeNG component reference directly.

Each PrimeNG visual component exports its module and component. For example [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/components/toolbar) you can see that in exported module is only ToolbarComponent and CommonModule), so you don't need to import whole module(if you render it programatically, as in example below), just the component (this may differ per component and it's requirements).

Here's short example of creating PrimeNG [Toolbar](https://primeng.org/toolbar) with Button and normal HTML elements that works for me (Angular 17.1.3, PrimeNG 17.6):

```
import { Toolbar } from 'primeng/toolbar';
import { Button } from 'primeng/button';

...

private viewRef = inject(ViewContainerRef);
private renderer = inject(Renderer2);

...     

private renderToolbar() {
    const parentElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    
    const toolbar = this.viewRef.createComponent(Toolbar);
    const toolbarGroupStart = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    toolbarGroupStart.setAttribute('class', 'p-toolbar-group-start');
    
    const toolbarMenuBtn = this.viewRef.createComponent(Button);
    toolbarMenuBtn.instance.styleClass = 'p-button-info';
    toolbarMenuBtn.instance.label = 'Menu';

    toolbarGroupStart.appendChild(toolbarMenuBtn.instance.el.nativeElement);
    
    toolbar.instance.getBlockableElement().appendChild(toolbarGroupStart);
    parentElement.appendChild(toolbar.instance.getBlockableElement());
    
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, parentElement);
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but to append toolbarMenuBtn to toolbarGroupStart it should be like this:  toolbarGroupStart.appendChild(toolbarMenuBtn.location.nativeElement);. And thanks for your answer.

Comment: According to documentation, `ComponentRef.location` contains host or anchor element for instance. 
I'd say it might be pointing to the same element in this case, since it's not appended anywhere yet, but using `ComponentRef.instance` seems to me like safer choice in this case. But feel free to prove me wrong please! :-)

https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef

Comment: Yeap I tried in stackblitz and it does work the way you did, but in my project i get this error: `Property 'el' does not exist on type 'Button'`, the error was found here `button.instance.el.nativeElement`. Probably related to some configuration option.